# express.js, stylus not compiling css

Tags: express, stylus

I'm getting the hang of Node.JS/Express.JS plus Stylus, but I have a problem. I tried a lot of things but stylus just wont compile my CSS. I googled it, stackoverflowed it, none of the solutions worked. I guess I'm missing something trivial or looking at the wrong angle. Can you help me out fix stylus to autocompile my css upon PUG template rendering?

Here is ths server.js:

```
    (function initialize(){
        //TODO: set dependencies
        var express = require('express');
        var http = require('http');
        var util = require('util');
        var stylus = require('stylus');
        var image = require('./routes/image');

        //TODO: set variables and constants
        var port = 8080;
        var hostname = 'localhost';

        //TODO: create express
        var app = express();

        //TODO: setup the template engine
        app.set('views', './views');
        app.set('view engine', 'pug');
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        app.use(stylus.middleware({
            src: __dirname + '/resources',
            dest: __dirname + '/public',
            debug: true,
            force: true
        }));

        //TODO: set the default GET route
        app.get('/', image.snatch);

        //TODO: create the server
        var server = http.createServer(app);

        //TODO: start the server
        server.listen(port, hostname, function start(){
            console.log(util.format('Server is running at http://%s:%s/', hostname, port));
        });
    }());
```

Here is the image.js:

```
    var snatchImage = function (req, res){
        var html = res.render('snatchImage',
            {
                title: 'Hey',
                message: 'Hello there!'
            });
        return res.send(html);
    };

    exports.snatch = snatchImage;
```

This is the PUG file:

```
    doctype html5
    html
        head
            title= title
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
        body
            div(rel='stylesheet', href='/style.css', class="selection")= message
```

If I missed something here is the git, maybe it will be more clear to view it like that. [Git link](https://github.com/victor-velchev/Node.js/tree/master/RemoteSnatcher).